# Why are so many pages getting read during an index scan (Postgres 11.2)?

Tags: postgresql

We have a Postgres 11.2 database which stores time-series of values against a composite key. Given 1 or a number of keys, the query tries to find the latest value(s) in each time-series given a time constraint.

We suffer query timeouts when the data is not cached, because it seems to have to walk a huge number of pages in order to find the data.

Here is the relevant section in the `explain`. We are getting the data for a single time-series (with 367 values in this example):

```
->  Index Scan using quotes_idx on quotes q  (cost=0.58..8.61 rows=1 width=74) (actual time=0.011..0.283 rows=367 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((client_id = c.id) AND (quote_detail_id = qd.id) AND (effective_at <= '2019-09-26 00:59:59+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND (effective_at >= '0001-12-31 23:58:45-00:01:15 BC'::timestamp with time zone))
Buffers: shared hit=374
```

This is the definition of the index in question:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX quotes_idx ON quotes.quotes USING btree (client_id, quote_detail_id, effective_at);
```

Where the columns are 2x `int4` and a `timestamptz`, respectively.

**Assuming I'm reading the output correctly, why is the engine walking 374 pages (~3Mb, given our 8kb page size) in order to return ~26kb of data (367 rows of width 74 bytes)?**

When we scale up the number of keys (say, 500) the engine ends up walking over 150k pages (over 1GB), which when not cached, takes a significant time.

Note, the average row size in the underlying table is 82 bytes (over 11 columns), and contains around 700mi rows.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: An index scan involves looking up rows in the index and then reading that row from the table. The number of buffers includes both. The mismatch between expected row (1) and actual rows (367) is a bit too high. Does the plan change if you run `analyze quotes` and try again? How many rows does the table have in total? Maybe a Seq Scan would have been better in this case.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I wondered about that... I estimated each page in the table would have about 100 rows (8kb page / 82 bytes). I appreciate a proportion of the 374 hit pages will be the index pages, but for arguments sake, even if half were index pages and the other half table pages, that'd still be 187 pages x 100 rows = 18.7k rows, just to return just 367...

Comment: Tried an `analyze` but didn't change the estimates unfortunately (presume it's struggling with the range query on the timestamptz column).

Table has 700mi rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 367 rows found in your index scan are probably stored in more than 300 table blocks (that is not surprising in a large table). So PostgreSQL has to access all these blocks to come up with a result.

This would perform much better if the rows were all concentrated in a few table blocks. In other words, if the logical ordering of the index would correspond to the physical order of the rows in the table. In PostgreSQL terms, a high [correlation](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/column-correlation-explained/) would be beneficial.

You can force PostgreSQL to rewrite the entire table in the correct order with

```
CLUSTER quotes USING quotes_idx;
```

Then your query should become much faster.

There are some disadvantages though:

- While `CLUSTER` is running, the table is not accessible. This usually means down time.
- Right after `CLUSTER`, performance will be good, but PostgreSQL does not maintain the ordering. Subsequent data modifications will reduce the correlation.

  To keep the query performing well, you'll have to schedule `CLUSTER` regularly.

Comment: Thanks very much! I was literally just about to try that when I saw the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` note in the docs... I'll wait until this evening, then try that in our test environment.

Out of question, do you know where I could find information on how Postgres chooses where to place new rows in blocks (given the absence of clustered indexes etc)?

Comment: Rows are placed in the first best block with enough free space. This information is managed in the *visibility map*.

Comment: Thanks - this worked! After clustering the table, the query only hits 3% of the number of pages that it had to do previously.

Comment: We are going to try using `pg_repack` to do online clustering, to avoid the exclusive table lock: http://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/

Answer (score 1):

Reading 374 blocks to obtain 367 rows is not unexpected.  CLUSTERing the data is one way to address that, as already mentioned.  Another possibility is to add some more columns into the index column list (by creating a new index and dropping the old one), so that the query can be satisfied with an index-only-scan.

This requires no down-time if the index is created concurrently. You do have to keep the table well-vacuumed, which can be tricky to do as the autovacuum parameters were really not designed with IOS in mind.  It requires no maintenance, other than the vacuuming, so I would prefer this method if the list (and size) of columns you need to add to the index is small.